# Connect Azure Function to Office 365 Flow

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a an application that uses Azure Function Preview. In Azure Function an API is created that delivers an small object with a value. I want to use this in a Office 365 Flow to send an email when value is larger than X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy. Your Azure Function has a url that can be access and that will return the object on a GET Verb.

To use it in Flow you create a new Flow application from the type "HTTP". In the HTTP action you add the url of your Azure Function.
Than you add a condition. In the condition action your define the rule to need to be true. You cannot have complex rules here, so you need to have a rule using contains to define if your object contains a certain value. I might be better not to return a object but a single value to have better fitting rule.
Than you can add another mail action that will create the email that is sent when the rule results in true.

Hope that this helps.
Sander